# In double value get Rounding numbers to 2 digits after comma in iOS OR objective c

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-category

here explain my code :

```
NSString *strDou = @"40.87";
strDou = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",[strDou floatValue]];
double d = [strDou doubleValue];
```

**In image you can see the value of 'd', at debug mode.**
[image]

**i got, d = 40.87**

**NSString *strDou = @"40.32"; this value work properly!!**

Comment: please explain in detail, what result you want ?

Comment: you want to get 40.87?

Comment: I think, it is impossible. Reason - sometimes finite decimal double like 40.87 is infitite in binary representation, like 1/3 is 0.3333333333333... in decimal, as the result when you convert this value to binary it becomes the nearest binary which can be written to double

Comment: NSString *strDou = @"40.3245214"; apply this it work.

Comment: Forgot that enter push the comment ). We have two decimal value - 0.25 and 0.26, when we convert it to binary double, we will get: 0.25 = 1/4 = binary 0.0100000000000; 0.0100001010001111
=0.25 + 0.0078125 + 0,001953125 + 0,0001220703125 + .... =1/4+1/128 +1/512 + 1/8192 + .... = binary 0.0100001010001... (and you can count that this value is not 0.26 actually), but if you can use only 8 bites, you have to drop or round all bites after 8 i.e. you will get 0.0100001. The same with 40.87 and 40.3245214, except the double has more bites

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)